# compute error from linear system - extract every column

Tags: c++, c, linear-algebra

I want to compute the error in linear least squares method.

I have matrices A,B and X. (AX=B).

Sizes are : A(NxN) , B(NxNRHS) , X(N,NRHS)  ,where NRHS is number of right hand side.

The error is computed as sqrt(sum(B-AX)).

But I must take into account every column of B and X in order to make the substraction.

I must substract  B[i]-A[..]X[i] -> where i is every column of B and X.

I can't figure how to do it ,hence how to extract every column.I can't find the right indices for B and X matrices (I think) ,because I must go beyond whole A matrix and only beyond every column of B and X.

I am doing something like this (using column major order):

```
int N=128;
int NRHS =1;
int Asize=N*N;
int Bsize=N*NRHS;
int Xsize=N*NRHS;

A=(double*)malloc(Asize*sizeof(double));  
B=(double*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(double));
X=(double*)malloc(Xsize*sizeof(double));
...

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0;j<NRHS; j++){

               diff[i+j*N] = fabs(B[i+j*N] - A[i+j*N]*X[i+j*N]);

               abs_error=sqrt(sums(diff,N));


        }
    }
```

I thought of adding some statement using the modulo operator but I couldn't figure.

sums is just a function which gives the sum of an array where the second argument is the number of elements.

Comment: How did you declare `A`, `B` and `X`? How are you passing them to the function? What is `sums()`?

Comment: @Filipe Gonçalves:I updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first do a matrix multiplication of `A` and `X` using loops.

Then you could write another 2 loops to compute the difference (`B - AX`). This would simply your problem.

**Edit**

After you compute the product of `A` and `X`, assuming that you store the product in a variable named `AX`,the following code will give you the difference between corresponding elements.

```
differenceMatrix = (double*)malloc(Bsize*sizeof(double));

for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < NRHS; j++){

           differenceMatrix[i+j*N] = fabs(B[i+j*N] - AX[i+j*N]);

    }
}
```

Each column of the differenceMatrix contains the difference between corresponding elements.

**Edit**

To obtain the sum of difference of each column

```
double sumOfDifferencePerColumn;
for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    sumOfDifferencePerColumn = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < NRHS; j++){

           sumOfDifferencePerColumn += ( fabs(B[i+j*N] - AX[i+j*N]) );

    }

    // add code to take square root or use the sum of difference of each column
}
```

Comment: :I tried that also.I can't figure again the loops and the indices.If you have in mind something and can show it..

Comment: @George What is the exact formula that you have to compute? For each column, do you have to find the sum, then add it and take square root?

Comment: :I want first to substract B-AX for every column of B,then add the result (sum) and then square root.